# Add bearer-token authentication with custom membership provider to existing Web API project

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token, custom-membershipprovider

I have an existing Web API project that currently has no authentication built in.

I want to add bearer-token based authentication, but I want to use a custom membership provider that I have used for other projects, although this has been with basic authentication.

There are some examples online that almost do what I need, but these have other technologies built-in that I don't want to use (e.g. Angular) or are not based on using a custom membership provider.

I could obviously do this using basic authentication, but I really don't want to.

How do I implement this?

Comment: did you solve the problem? As I have MVC4 project with SimpleMembershipProvider and would like to add webapi 2 and implement token based authentication. If you happen to solve this please cane you give me some hints. Thank you.